# What is the proper way to add subroutine to handle the connection string in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, connection-string

I have a app.config and a connection string that works perfectly.

App.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString"
         connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseC;Data Source=agent_edx44-PC;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

My Form

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;         
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspINSERT",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    .....some code
}

private void bindDataGrid()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspSELECTALL",con);
    cmd.Connection = con;
   ...some code

}
```

My problem is I want to put this line of code inside a subroutine so that I can call it in any methods.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

**Here is what i have done so far:**

```
private void MyConnection()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyConnection()
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspINSERT",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    .....some code
}
```

But it has an error saying that:

> The name 'con' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You've got some bad code here. Most of the SQL objects implement `IDisposable` so you must use a `using` block or call `.Dispose()` when you're done with each object.

Comment: @Enigmativity Can you please help me with my code? I am new to c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you should write those first two methods:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspINSERT", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
            //.....some code
        }
    }
}

private void bindDataGrid()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspSELECTALL", con))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            //...some code
        }
    }
}
```

Now,to get your new code to work you need to return the connection from the `MyConnection` method:

```
private SqlConnection MyConnection()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    return con;
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = MyConnection())
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspINSERT", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
            //.....some code
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would go one step further and do this:

```
private void RunSqlCommand(string cmdText, Action<SqlConnection, SqlCommand> execute)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            execute(con, cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `btnSave_Click` method can become this:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RunSqlCommand("uspINSERT", (con, cmd) =>
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        //.....some code
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It works like a charm. I'm happy to learn new things now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your MyConnection method to this, it returns a SqlConnection:

```
private SqlConnection MyConnection()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    return con;
}
```

This is how to use:

```
using (var con = MyConnection()) 
{
   //your code
}
```

`using` block will dispose your DB connection after you have done with it.